# How to use sqlalchemy.orm.validates on Null field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a class:
I have a field `special_pin` that can be null, but cannot be null in a specific context. I want to validate that field by writing a validation function (`validates_pin`). However the validation function won't run when the `special_pin` field is null.

See my code below

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class User(db.Model):
  user_type = db.column(db.String, nullable=False)
  special_pin = db.column(db.String)

  @validates('special_pin')
  def validates_pin(self, key, field):
  if self.user_type == 'special'
    assert field, 'special user must have special pin'
```

Comment: By "field is null" do you mean that you never assign to `special_pin` attribute? Include a [mcve]. Your case seems like a good fit for a check constraint, if your DB supports them.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. I'm using postgreSQL, how should I go about creating the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`validates()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates) validator "receives the name of the attribute as well as a value to be assigned, or in the case of a collection, the value to be added to the collection". So if the field is not touched, no validation occurs. Your use case would seem like a good fit for a table level [check constraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint):

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    special_pin = db.Column(db.String)

    __table_args__ = (
        # Note the trailing comma. __table_args__ should be a tuple or a dict.
        db.CheckConstraint("user_type != 'special' OR special_pin IS NOT NULL",
                           name="check_special_user_has_pin"),
    )
```